# Minecraft Sign Command give tool help [1.8]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a command that summons a sign that you can buy a certain item from, however I keep on getting a error with inserting the lore and the custom name, the command that I have used is,

```
/give @p sign 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Text1:"[{\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/tellraw @p[score_Grains=0] {\\\"text\\\":\\\"You do not have enough Grains to buy that\\\",\\\"color\\\":\\\"dark_red\\\"}\"},\"text\":\"[Buy]\",\"bold\":\"true\"}]",Text2:"[{\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/tellraw @p[score_Grains_min=1] {\\\"text\\\\\\\":\\\"You just bought 1 Test for $1\\\",\\\"color\\\":\\\"dark_green\\\"}\"},\"text\":\"Test\",\"underlined\":\"true\"}]",Text3:"[{\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/give @p[score_Grains_min=1] minecraft:paper 1 0 {display:{Name:"Test",Lore:["Test"]},ench:[{id:0,lvl:10}]}\"},\"text\":\"$1\",\"color\":\"green\"}]",Text4:"[{\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/scoreboard players remove @p[score_Grains_min=1] Grains 1\"},\"text\":\"1\"}]"},display:{Name:"Buy Test"}}
```

However, there is a error message which is,

```
[13:21:48] Data tag parsing failed: Unexpected token 'T' at: Test",Lore:["Test"]},ench:[{id:0,lvl:10}]}\"},\"text\":\"$1\",\"color\":\"green\"}]",Text4:"[{\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/scoreboard players remove @p[score_Grains_min=1] Grains 1\"},\"text\":\"1\"}]"
```

What is wrong? And how do I fix this?

Comment: It would be more helpful to copy/paste the actual command text being used instead of an image of the text.

Comment: Before `ench` you closed your last `{ }`, so this goes nowhere. That's why it fails. Please count your brackets or post the command as text, so we can read it properly. There might be other syntax errors.

Comment: @Skylinerw There, I added the command instead of the image.

Comment: @dly I have tried that, however I still get the same error.

Comment: That was just one mistake I found on the first view. There may still be more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax should be fine with this one:

(Using the actual functionality is up to you. I haven't tested the scoreboard values, but now you have something to start working with.)

```
/give @p sign 1 0 {
    BlockEntityTag: {
        Text1: "{\"text\":\"[Buy]\",\"color\":\"dark_red\",\"bold\":true,\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/tellraw @p[score_Grains=0] [\\\"text\\\":\\\"You do not have enough Grains to buy that\\\",\\\"color\\\":\\\"dark_red\\\"}]\"}}",
        Text2: "{\"text\":\"Test\",\"color\":\"dark_green\",\"underlined\":true,\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/tellraw @p[score_Grains_min=1] [\\\"text\\\":\\\"You just bought 1 Test for 1$\\\",\\\"color\\\":\\\"dark_green\\\"}]\"}}",
        Text3: "{\"text\":\"$1\",\"color\":\"green\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/give @p[score_Grains_min=1] minecraft:paper 1 0 {display:{Name:Test,Lore:[Test]},ench:[{id:0,lvl:10}]}\"}}",
        Text4: "{\"text\":\"1\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/scoreboard players remove @p[score_Grains_min=1] Grains 1\"}}"    },
    display: {
        Name: "Test Buy"    
  }
}
```

[image: Sign]

Comment: It works, I have a question, if I want to add more enchantments to that item, how do I so without messing the whole thing up?

Comment: Can I use this concept as a sell sign as well? And how?

Comment: @Desterious You can alter the part `ench:[{id:0,lvl:10},{id:1,lvl:10},{id:2,lvl:10}]` to adjust your desired enchantments. If you want somethig completely new please ask a new question.